# Using restore-pnprecyclebinitems for sub-site use only

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell, recycle-bin

We have some files missing on a sub-site from which I have tried to use a script to restore.

I connect to the context using `connect-pnponline` giving the specific team address `t5\ts1`. I confirm context using `get-pnpweb` which is correct.

When I get the recycle bin count using `(get-pnprecyclebin).count` it gives me the parent sites recycle bin count and not the current context. Subsequently, if i use `get-pnprecyclebin | restore-pnprecyclebin` it will restore items from the Parent, onwards.

How would I specify that I require only items from the current context to be restored. i.e the Sub Site only.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When running this command, it is prudent to try to execute it using a user that only has access to the data you require restored.

Using a Site Collection Administrator account, as I was, was rendering all my Current Parent site context content.

There are clearly dangerous consequences to this command.